# cp --attributes-only documented but not working "now"?

Tags: linux, cp, copy-paste, coreutils

**PROBLEM**: `cp --attributes-only Source Target` results in two files unchanged, where the attributes from *Source* should be copied to *Target*.

**Attempts to solve**: As I have the **8.13** version of `coreutils` installed [Aha?], I wonder why this option is mentioned, but doesn't seem to work. No error messages, no nothing, even when running it with `--verbose`. The same goes when trying to copy the attributes from various accounts. Nothing.

In `cp`'s man page I found the option

`--attributes-only ->
          don't copy the file data, just the attributes`

In [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45436/36242) I found that

> With recent versions of GNU coreutils (≥ **8.6**), you can use cp
>   --attributes-only to replicate the metadata … of a file on another file without changing the target file's contents.

[In another posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11946544), someone mentions to be working in Ubuntu, but then there are remarks that I doesn't work on Mac OS X.

**QUESTION**: Where am I wrong? Could it be the older version of coreutils - and if so, why is there something documented that doesn't work »now«?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The info docs (accessed by running `info cp` or [online](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html#cp-invocation)) have the clue

```
`--attributes-only'
     Copy only the specified attributes of the source file to the
     destination.  If the destination already exists, do not alter its
     contents.  See the `--preserve' option for controlling which
     attributes to copy.
```

So try adding `--preserve`, `--preserve=context`, `--preserve=all`, `--archive`, or similar, depending on which attributes you want to copy.

`cp --preserve --attributes-only...` works for me with coreutils 8.20.

Comment: Oh… I didn't see the connection :)