# How to avoid that Geany editor changes owner of file when it's edited?

Tags: permissions, group, editors, geany

I use Geany to edit files in a web app that resides in `/var/www`. The owner and group of `/var/www` and all sub directories and files are `www-data:www-data`. My user account is a member of that group and I edit the files as my user. Sometimes it seems Geany changes the owner and group of the edited file to my user and my group.

**How can I make sure the user:group is never changed when I edit a file with Geany?**

---

I found this clue in the Geany help:

> **use_atomic_file_saving**
>
> Defines the mode how Geany saves files to disk. If disabled, Geany
>   directly writes the content of the document to disk. This might cause
>   loss of data when there is no more free space on disk to save the
>   file. When set to true, Geany first saves the contents into a
>   temporary file and if this succeeded, the temporary file is moved to
>   the real file to save. This gives better error checking in case of no
>   more free disk space. But it also destroys hard links of the original
>   file and its permissions (e.g. executable flags are reset). Use this
>   with care as it can break things seriously. The better approach would
>   be to ensure your disk won't run out of free space.

As of now it's disabled, meaning that the file is written directly, which I thought would prevent my problem from happening.

This questions contains some relevant info:
[How do I edit a file and preserve its access control list / SELinux security context?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45407)

Comment: I thought it was a bad idea to have your www files owned by www-data, because if your server is compromised, you don't want the user gaining access to change the files.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [Geany's wiki](http://wiki.geany.org/config/all_you_never_wanted_to_know_about_file_saving), it looks like you might also need to disable this option:

> **use_gio_unsafe_file_saving**
>
> > This is on by the default, and is provided by the GIO library.
> >
> > This option attempts to deal with as many of the issues associated with the other methods as it can:
> >
> > - It attempts to use the atomic rename saving method described above, but tries to address as many issues as it can:
> >
> >   - it checks metadata of the temporary file and tries to copy the metadata from the existing file,
> >   - if the metadata is correct, it writes to the temporary and renames as above,
> >   - if the metadata is not correct, it uses a non-atomic but safe method of:
> >
> >     - copying the existing file to a temporary file
> >     - truncating and overwriting the existing file, if this fails the temporary file should be copied back or available, but see disadvantages below.
> > - It attempts to determine if rename is available on the underlying file system, and uses the non-atomic method if rename fails.
> >
> > Advantages:
> >
> > - Deals with the most different conditions, so works the most correctly on the most file systems. That is why it is the default.
> >
> > Disadvantages:
> >
> > - There is a [long standing bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=602412) or design fault in the GIO library that deletes the temporary file from the non-atomic save if writing the data file fails. **This means it is no more safe than the simple overwrite method since the previous data is not restored, or even left available for the user to restore.**
> > - The non-atomic save copies data over the network three times (read and write to make the temporary file, write the output file) which can be slow on remote networks.
> > - Uses twice the disk space.
> > - Is quite complex.
> > - Uses library code so Geany can't modify its behaviour

What a strange method of file saving.  It appears that it can result in the same "atomic" save as the `use_atomic_file_saving` option.

Comment: Looks very likely that this was the catch! :) I will try this for a couple of days of work, and come back with feedback when tested.