# server file owner and group changed when editing file locally

Tags: files, permissions, editors, geany

If i edit the file from a remote server via text editor (geany, sublime text..etc) locally, the file user and group will changed to the logged user.

Let say if I accessing the remote file with root user (using caja file manager)

Before root user edit:
file member:admin

After root user edit:
file root:root

How do I prevent this?

**UPDATE**
If I edit the files remotely with VIM, the owner and group remain the same. So, I think maybe it is related to the text editor??

Comment: If you edit an existing file it shouldn't change anything.

Comment: That's what I thought, but the truth is opposite.

Comment: Since this depends on the editor and you didn't focus the question on a specific editor, I've closed your question as a duplicate of a generic one about this issue. If you want to know how to force ownership preservation on a specific editor, first make sure that you understand that this may result in data loss, then edit your question to focus on that specific editor. But you should not edit files as root!

Answer (score 0):

In this case , root has permission to write to the directory, so root's editor writes a file /path/file.tmp (or some similar name) then moves the new file to /path/file. Since root just created the file, it is owned by root. This is how some of the editors work by default.

For more help about editors and preserving file permissions etc , see the link below:

"...instruct your editor to edit the file in place. With Vim, set the  backupcopy option to yes, if that isn't the default on your system. With Emacs, set the backup-by-copying variable to t ..."

[More Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45407/how-do-i-edit-a-file-and-preserve-its-access-control-list-selinux-security-con/45436#45436)

Comment: No, I am editing existing files not created new one.

Comment: yes , i haven't said that you are creating new ones , it is how the editors work. as said in the answer , the editor creates a new temp file itself...because it's not editing the file `in-place`

Comment: I got what you meant. So, this is text editor related issue. I am using geany or sublime text, not sure how to configure them.

Comment: then that is a different question :) i haven't used geany or sublime